# How do i use NSSharingService To Compose An Email With Attachment?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

I am attempting to open the default email client in Mac with an Attachment.

Since my application is in JAVA, i need to resort to the native code capabilities to achieve the same.

I need to open the default email client with an attachment and the To, Subject & Body configured.

I probably can use NSSharing Service, but does someone have experience with the same and can guide me to material or a working example.

Comment: A working Example is provided here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414974/nssharingservice-to-send-email-and-read-email-body