# How to attach files using NSSharingService

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, thunderbird, nssharingservice

I am preparing a Mail using `NSSharingService`. I mainly followed the advice given here: [NSSharingService to send email and read email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414974/nssharingservice-to-send-email-and-read-email-body)

Effectively I am calling

`[self.emailSharingService performWithItems:shareItems];`

where `shareItems` is an `NSArray` containing one `NSString` object (the body) and several `NSURL` objects (the attachements)

With AppleMail the preparation of the mail works fine (e.g. body & attachments) but unfortunately the attachments are not added if I use another mail client (e.g. Thunderbird, Spark)

Does anyone know how I can achieve the addition of the attachments in other mail clients than AppleMail?

Comment: Have you found an answer in the 4 years that have passed 

Comment: @jayesh Thanki -- I, too, have the exact same question: Did you ever figure this out?  I've run into this issue and of course Apple Developer support is not going to provide any assistance.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. I just checked my old code - it still does not work with other mail clients. Actually we circumvented the problem by building our own in-App-Mail-Client.